# Wire not centered in the connector (electrical circuits)

Tags: tikz-pgf

Why isn't the wire centered in the connector located at the point `(2.5,0)`?

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{circuits.logic.IEC}
\tikzset{circuit declare symbol = ammeter}
\tikzset{set ammeter graphic ={draw,generic circle IEC, minimum size=5mm,info=center:A}}
\tikzset{circuit declare symbol = vmmeter}
\tikzset{set vmmeter graphic ={draw,generic circle IEC, minimum size=5mm,info=center:V}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC,every info/.style=red,
set resistor graphic=var resistor IEC graphic]

\draw (0,0) 
to[battery] (0,2) to [make contact](3,2)
to [ammeter] (3,0)--(2.5,0)
to [vmmeter] (.5,0)--(0,0);
\draw (0,0)--(.5,0) to[contact={at start}] (.5,-2) to[resistor={info={R ($\Omega$)}}] (2.5,-2) to[contact={at end}] (2.5,0)--(3,0);\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's a rounding problem. You can use `\draw (.5,0) to[contact={at start}] (.5,-2) to[resistor={info={R ($\Omega$)}}] (2.5,-2) to[contact={pos=0.99999}] (2.5,0);`. Notice also that you had some spurious paths in your `\draw` command.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It shouldn't be like that but I don't understand why. Here is a work around.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}
%\usetikzlibrary{circuits.logic.IEC}
\tikzset{circuit declare symbol = ammeter}
\tikzset{set ammeter graphic ={draw,generic circle IEC, minimum size=5mm,info=center:A}}
\tikzset{circuit declare symbol = vmmeter}
\tikzset{set vmmeter graphic ={draw,generic circle IEC, minimum size=5mm,info=center:V}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC,every info/.style=red,
set resistor graphic=var resistor IEC graphic]

 \draw (0,0)
to[battery] (0,2) to [make contact](3,2)
to [ammeter] (3,0)--(2.5,0)
to [vmmeter] (.5,0)--(0,0);
\draw (0,0)--(.5,0) to[contact={at start}] (.5,-2) to[resistor={info={R ($\Omega$)}}] (2.5,-2) to (2.5,0)node[contact] {}--(3,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A PSTricks solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-circ}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\newcommand*\device[3]{%
  \circledipole[labeloffset = 0](#1)(#2){\textcolor{red}{\si{#3}}}}


\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-0.5,-0.25)(6.5,7.5)
  \pnodes{P}(1,0)(5,0)(0,4)(1,4)(5,4)(6,4)(0,7)(6,7)
 {\psset{arrows = -*}
  \wire(P0)(P3)
  \wire(P1)(P4)}
  \resistor[dipolestyle = zigzag](P0)(P1){\textcolor{red}{$R$~(\si{\ohm})}}
  \device{P3}{P4}{\V}
  \device{P5}{P7}{\A}
  \wire(P2)(P3)
  \wire(P4)(P5)
  \battery(P2)(P6){}
  \newSwitch[ison = false](P6)(P7){}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Note that [`pst-circ`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pst-circ) is used for the electrical diagram itself and [`siunitx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) is used for the units.